# Testing Platform Events that are published from Process Builder

Tags: platform-event

I need to test that in some cases platform events are published from a process builder. Does event are not meant to be consumed in the platform but outside the platform, so I have no triggers or automation wired on it.

How are these scenario tested?

Comment: did you try using Limits class in a testmethod?

Comment: Which limit ? Do they count as a dml statement ?

Comment: Yes they do.  DML statements and rows